# how to read data from excel file in python WITH THE FILE PATH AS A COLUMN in the output

Tags: python, excel

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

all_data = pd.DataFrame() 
rows = 0
for file in glob.glob("Ranking*.xlsx"):
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    sheets = xls.sheet_names

    for sheet_name in sheets:
        df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Output',header= 3)

    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index = True)
    output_tab_data = all_data[['Supplier','Tariff','Region']]
    output_tab_data_no_NA = output_tab_data[output_tab_data.Supplier.notnull()]
    output_tab_data_no_NA ['file_source_name'] = os.path.abspath(file)

    print(output_tab_data_no_NA)
```

The above code produces the these columns at the moment - 
'Supplier','Tariff','Region'

But i want this to include an EXTRA COLUMN named file_source_name -  that is the excel file name path from each excel file loaded

Comment: Did you try this out? ```output_tab_data_no_NA ['file_source_name'] = file```, if you want the absolute file_path, you can use - ```output_tab_data_no_NA ['file_source_name'] = os.path.abspath(file)```

Comment: Thanks Cavin. But this doesn't do exactly what I need it to do. I am reading data from 3 excel files like ranking_a.xlxs,  ranking_b.xlxs, and  ranking_c.xlxs. So I need to see ranking_a.xlxs,  ranking_b.xlxs, and  ranking_c.xlxs in file_source_name. What you have suggested only appends just ranking_a.xlxs. Thanks for your help

Comment: A big thank you to Cavin Dsouza!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

all_data = pd.DataFrame() #creating an empty data frame
rows = 0
for f in glob.glob("../<path where python is>/*.xlsx"): #import every file that ends in .xls
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    sheets = xls.sheet_names # To get names of all the sheets
    for sheet_name in sheets:
             df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Output',header= 3) #start copying data from line 4 in each file
             df['file_source_name'] = f  #append individual file name/file path
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index = True) #put all the copied data together
    output_tab_data = all_data[['Supplier','Tariff','Region','file_source_name']]
    output_tab_data_no_NA = output_tab_data[output_tab_data.Supplier.notnull()]
print(output_tab_data_no_NA)
```